# Creating a function to pass dataframes as parameters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, variable-assignment

I have a hypothetical dataframe 'country_sales_df' :

```
country_sales_list_of_lists =  
[
['Australia',21421324,342343,'Pacific','Y'],
['England',124233431,43543464,'Europe','Y'], 
['Japan',12431241341,34267545,'Asia','N'],
['India',214343421,342343,'Asia','Y']
]

country_sales_df = pd.DataFrame(country_sales_list_of_lists,columns = ['Country','Sales',Profit,Region,Otac_Group])
```

I then define a series of dataframes from the original country sales dataframe:

```
otac_df= country_sales_df.query('Otac_Group == "Y"')

asia_df= country_sales_df.query('Region == "Asia"')

europe_df= country_sales_df.query('Region == "Europe"')

pacific_df= country_sales_df.query('Region == "Pacific"')
```

For each of the dataframes I want to aggregate all the numeric fields and create an additional dataframe with the aggregated information. I don't want to have to repeat the agg code for each dataframe as the actual project I'm working on will have significantly more lines of code, this is just a smaller example.

How would I create a function to do this? I tried the below but it will return an error 'TypeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object is not callable'

```
def country_report_func(df_name,region_df):
    df_name =  region_df.groupby('Country')(['Sales','Profit']).agg([np.sum])

country_report_func('pacific_df_agg',pacific_df)
country_report_func('europe_df_agg',europe_df)
country_report_func('asia_df_agg',asia_df)
country_report_func('otac_df_agg',otac_df)
```

I'm basically just trying to get a piece of code to run for each of the dataframes I have defined and produce an additional dataframe for each. Does anyone have any recommendations on the best way to do this? I.e loop through a list of dataframes etc ?

Update:
I have now updated the function so it is applying the agg function to a datframe object and look to return the dataframe within the function. This is now returning the pacific_df_agg, however I'm unable to print this. The Europe, Asia and otac dataframes are also not created.

```
def country_report_func(df_name,region_df):
    df_name =  region_df.groupby('Country')[['Sales','Profit']].agg([np.sum])
    return df_name

country_report_func('pacific_df_agg',pacific_df)
country_report_func('europe_df_agg',europe_df)
country_report_func('asia_df_agg',asia_df)
country_report_func('otac_df_agg',otac_df)
```

Update 2:

I think I have solved it as I am now returning multiple dataframes for the function using the below code. Unsure if this is the easiest way to do this if anyone has any further suggestions:

```
def country_report_func(df_name,region_df):
    df_name =  region_df.groupby('Country')[['Sales','Profit']].agg([np.sum])
    return df_name

pacific_df_agg = country_report_func('pacific_df_agg',pacific_df)
europe_df_agg = country_report_func('europe_df_agg',europe_df)
asia_df_agg = country_report_func('asia_df_agg',asia_df)
otac_df_agg = country_report_func('otac_df_agg',otac_df)

print(pacific_df_agg)
print(europe_df_agg)
print(asia_df_agg)
print(otac_df_agg)
```

Comment: If you use `inplace=True` in `where` there is no output, remove this parameter

Comment: Thanks I updated to remove the inplace argument and any other syntax problems. I received an warning message for the indexing, however the function still isn't returning any dataframes (message is that the dataframes are not defined), so I'm unsure what the function is doing in this case.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `region_df.groupby('Country')(['Sales','Profit'])`, exactly what do you think this means, **step by step**? In particular: what kind of thing do you expect to get from `region_df.groupby('Country')`? What do you think should happen if you then put `(['Sales','Profit'])` after that? (Hint: see how there are `()` around `(['Sales','Profit'])`? See how the error message says something about something being "not callable"? Does that seem related?)

Comment: 1. We would be grouping the region_df by the country field essentially creating a group by object region_df.groupby('Country') 2. Apply the agg function to that group summing on the Sales and profit columns. I have since changed this part so its a dataframe object.. df_name =  region_df.groupby('Country')[['Sales','Profit']].agg([np.sum])